# Письмо на email Java EE

Tags: email, java-ee

Подскажите есть какие-то утилиты для `Java EE` что бы отсылать `e-mail` письма?
Видел стандартные `java`-вские но они устарели. Нашел штуку от `Apache` ошибку выдаёт:

## HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

**type** Exception report

**message** Servlet execution threw an exception

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException
    de.sniff.Sniff.SendEmail(Sniff.java:343)
    de.sniff.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:23)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    de.sniff.Sniff.SendEmail(Sniff.java:343)
    de.sniff.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:23)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.8 logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/8.5.8

Почему - понять не могу.

Подскажите есть ли ещё какие-то приблуды?

Answer (score 1):

JavaMail - Java API предназначенное для получения и отправки электронной почты с использованием протоколов SMTP, POP3 и IMAP.
Является составной частью JavaEE.

На википедии 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaMail можно даже пример увидеть.

Но есть проблема.
JavaEE имеет два профиля, отличающихся набором включенных спецификаций: Full Profile и урезанный Web profile.
JavaMail из Web-профиля випилен нахрен, как и много чего другого.
Tomcat обеспечивает только Web profile.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/AddressException`, `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException` как раз являются подтверждением этого. Классы из JavaMail не обнаружены.

Казалось бы с JavaMail Вы в пролёте.
Но ничто не мешает скачать библиотеку JavaMail и установить её на свой сервер (в папку общих библиотек) либо включить в веб-приложение. https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release